# Trying to find record using $in in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find record using $in in mongoose. But it's not working for me. I have same query in mongo shell its working but in mongoose it is not workinh
my schema

```
{
      "_id": "574f1f979f44e7531786c80f",
      "name": "mySchool2",
      "branch": "karachi",
      "location": "Clifton ",
      "block": false,
      "created_at": 1464803223441,
      "updated_at": 1464803223441,
      "__v": 0,
      "classes": [
        "574f216afd487958cd69772a"
      ],
      "admin": [
        "574f20509f44e7531786c811",
        "57508a2a3a0a919c16ace3c0"
      ],
      "teacher": [
        "574f20f39f44e7531786c812",
        "575002b48188a3f821c2a66e",
        "57500bbaea09bc400d047bf6"
      ],
      "student": [
        "574f2d56590529c01a2a473b",
        "574f2e5842c5885b1b1729ab",
        "574f2ed542c5885b1b1729ae",
        "574f2f57555210991bf66e07",
        "574f2fcd087809b11bd8d5e4",
        "574f301d1f5025d61b7392b6",
        "574f30481d02afff1bb00c71",
        "574f30b01d02afff1bb00c74",
        "574f310038136b3d1cf31b96"
      ]
    }
```

My mongose  query

```
app.services._chkAdminSchool = function(payload){
        var deferred = q.defer();
        School
            //.find({ teacher:{$in:['574f20f39f44e7531786c812']}})

            .find({_id : "574f1f979f44e7531786c80f",admin:{"$in":[Object("57508a2a3a0a919c16ace3c0")]}})
            //.select(filers)
            .exec(function(error, record) {
                if (error) {
                    deferred.reject({
                        status:404,
                        message: 'Error in API',
                        error: error
                    });
                } else {
                    if(record.length === 0){
                        deferred.reject({
                            message: 'Admin and school doesnot match',
                            data: record
                        });
                    }else{
                        deferred.resolve({
                            message: 'Successfully get Admin',
                            data: record
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

records are return empty array. 
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: 'var SchoolSchema = new Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        branch: {type: String},
        location: {type: String},
        block: {type: Boolean},
        webURL: {type: String},
        created_at: {type: Number},
        updated_at: {type: Number},
        student: {type:Array},
        teacher: {type:Array},
        admin: {type:Array},
        classes: {type:Array}

    });'

Comment: This my schema, I have tried both ObjectID and simple id string for finding the admin. but its not working

Answer (score 0):

The query you use works fine for me and returns object, make sure you define admin field in Schema like this:

```
"admin": [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId }]
```

to avoid admin array object being string. If you compare `Object("57508a2a3a0a919c16ace3c0")` to `"57508a2a3a0a919c16ace3c0"` it will return empty array, check and replay to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you define your School Schema, but if you are saving `id` in `admin` array as String, you don't need to change to Object in your mongoose query.

```
School.find({
  _id: "574f1f979f44e7531786c80f",
  admin: {
    $in : ['57508a2a3a0a919c16ace3c0']
  }
}, functin (err, record) {
...
})
```